# "От всех" или "ото всех"?

Tags: орфография

Как лучше сказать: "от всех" или "ото всех"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В толковых словарях похожие, как близнецы, словарные статьи: (правда, в каких-то со словосочетанием  *в разговорной речи,* в каких-то без этого уточнения). *Ото* (без удар.), предлог. То же, что *от*. Употребляется в разговорной речи наряду с *от*, но реже, перед словами, начинающимися с некоторых групп согласных: *ото всего, ото всей, ото всех, ото льна, ото многого, многой, многих, ото сна* (при *от всего и т. д.*) и обычно в сочетании *"день ото дня"*.
Строгой регламентации в пособиях по культуре речи не встречала. Я воспринимаю вариант *ото всех* как правильный, но устаревающий.